# How do I perform mathematical operation in my String Builder?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

In my controller I am pulling some information using WCF. To make it simple I have put everything in a `StringBuilder()` and iterate my information from my list through a `foreach` loop like so:

```
var myResult = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var myFruit in response.GetContestResult.ContestEndTimes.ToList())
    htmlResult.AppendFormat("{0} Avg End Time: {1} <br/>", myFruit.ContestantName, myfruit.ContestantEndTime);

return myResult.ToString();
```

My `endTimes` show up as seconds and I want to change to minutes by dividing the `myFruit.CotestantWaitTime` by 60. I tried changing it to:

```
htmlResult.AppendFormat("{0} Avg End Time: {1} <br/>", myFruit.ContestantName, 
Int32.Parse(myfruit.ContestantEndTime) / 60);

return myResult.ToString();
```

But, then the error reads that the string is in an incorrect format, and does the same even if I convert it back to a string like:

```
Convert.ToString(Int32.Parse(myfruit.ContestantEndTime) / 60))
```

How should I be doing this?

[image: Proof that ContestantEndTime is a string]

Comment: typo in here not in code

Comment: Can you give us an example of ContestantEndTime? Perhaps the issue is in parsing that to an Int

Comment: I changed my variables around asking the question and made some typos

Comment: You can [edit] your post and fix them..

Comment: I have made the edits suggested

Comment: "1223" is an example of what it shows up in the post without trying to convert it. is this what you are asking @Vlad274

Comment: If `ContestantEndTime` is a `string`. Make sure it *can* be parsed, before you parse it. Try `Int32.TryParse()` instead.

Comment: wrapping a tryParse around it wil give an overload error saying it takes 1 argument. Instead of tryParse and Parse I have also tried Convert.To

Comment: @Vlad274 is not asking what "shows in the post", show us what is in `myFruit.ContestantEndTime`. You know how to use debugger and stop when the exception is thrown, right? And watching the variables.

Comment: @IvanStoev When I hover over `.ContestantEndTime` Intellesense tells me that it is a string. I hope this is answering your question?

Comment: Omg. What is **in** that string?

Comment: That can't be true. `Int32.Parse("1223")` will pass - no exception. Try again. And are you sure it's not "12:23" for instance?

Comment: Anyway, the code you posted should work if the `ContestantEndTime` contains a number as you claim, but apparently it doesn't. I'm taking off this, good luck.

Comment: @IvanStoev I posted what you requested. I, like you do not understand why it does not work. Thanks for your time

Comment: Ok, sorry. If that's the case, the only thing I can think of is if the string contains some non printable character. Try `myfruit.ContestantEndTime.Length` in the Immeadiate or Watch window and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd wager that there is a format error in one or more of the contestants end times.

What you need to do, is to use [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx).
You should also perform a `null` check.

```
foreach (var myFruit in response.GetContestResult.ContestEndTimes.ToList())
{
    // -1 will imply that there is an error.
    int parsedTime = -1;

    if (myfruit.ContestantEndTime != null && 
        Int32.TryParse(myfruit.ContestantEndTime, out parsedTime))
    {
        parsedTime /= 60;
    }

    htmlResult.AppendFormat("{0} Avg End Time: {1} <br/>", 
        myFruit.ContestantName, 
        parsedTime);
}
```

This will work regardless of what `myFruit.ContestantEndTime` is `null`, `"foo"` or `"37281"`. And you can easily identify where there are errors.

The real question here is... Why is `myFruit.ContestantEndTime` not an int (or any other number-type) from the get-go?

Answer (score 0):

If myfruit.ContestantEndTime is an int then int.Parse will throw an error because this method takes a string as a parameter.  If this is the case you don't need to do anything to it before dividing it and can just use:

```
htmlResult.AppendFormat("{0} Avg End Time: {1} <br/>", myFruit.ContestantName, 
myfruit.ContestantEndTime / 60);
```

Comment: I have tried this first. This gives the error `'/' cannot be applied to operands of type string and int`

Comment: This can't be true. If it's an `int`, `int.Parse` will not throw exception, because the code won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

If `myFruit.ContestantEndTime` is of `int` type,

```
htmlResult.AppendFormat("{0} Avg End Time: {1} ",
                                   myFruit.ContestantName, myFruit.ContestantEndTime/60);
```

If it is a `string` type, fist convert it to an Int value using `Convert.ToInt32` method.

```
htmlResult.AppendFormat("{0} 3Avg End Time: {1} ",
                   myFruit.ContestantName, Convert.ToInt32(myFruit.ContestantEndTime)/60);
```

The above 2 will generate an integer representation of the minute (with no reminders). That means, if your `ContestantEndTime` value is `240` or `245`, It will return just `4`. But If you want extra seconds, you can try this

```
htmlResult.AppendFormat("{0} Avg End Time: {1}.{2} ", myFruit.ContestantName,
                               myFruit.ContestantEndTime/60, myFruit.ContestantEndTime%60);
```

Now when you have 245 in `myFruit.ContestantEndTime`, The above expression will give you `4.2`